# Azure AD in ASP.NET Core MVC web application causes CORB for JavaScript requests

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory, iis-8, asp.net-core-2.1, cross-origin-read-blocking

**Integration of Azure AD into a ASP.NET Core MVC web application causes Cross-Origin Read Blocking for requests made by JavaScript frontend to ASP.NET controllers.**

I am writing an ASP.NET Core MVC application that requires users to login using a Microsoft work account. This works. I added the following code to Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/SignIn/";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied/";
});
```

I am also using Telerik UI widgets for the applications user interface. Because of this, there are multiple places where I use JavaScript to make requests to my ASP.NET controllers. Ex:

```
function onEvent(e) {

    $.post("Controller/Foo", function (data) {
        ...
    });
}
```

This works great when I'm running and debugging locally using IIS Express but when I deploy the application to our server running IIS I start getting warnings about Cross-Origin Read Blocking in my browsers development tools and none of my javascript functions that make requests to my ASP.NET controllers receive data.

Here is a screenshot of the warnings:

[image]

If anyone happens to know how to approach this problem I would be very grateful; I'm new to all of this and I have no idea where to start with this particular problem.

My current thinking is either I need to figure out how to handle the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in javascript or that there is something that needs to be done in Azure.

The first thing I did was enable CORS in my application but that just allows other domains to make cross-origin requests from my application, which isn't what's happening here.

Comment: do check this which might help - https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/853

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this issue with CORB in Chrome and dotnet core please note that in my case I was using the ResponseCache attribute. On the first non cached request it worked and subsequent ones failed with CORB error.

Once I removed the attribute the error went away.

This does not solve the issue but gives one some direction as to where the issue might be.

I did not bother with the response cache as it's no longer needed.

Below was the offending code

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 15, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any, VaryByQueryKeys = new[] {"key", "type", "identifier", "app"})]
```